# How To Pass Handler with Variable Number of Arguments To A Class Using Boost Library If Needed

Tags: c++, function, boost, bind, boost-asio

This question has been haunting me for several days.  It looks very simple, but it's very difficult for me to figure it out.

Basically, I want to do something like the async_wait function in the following code snippet

```
boost::asio::io_services    io;
boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(io);
timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000));
timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&FunctionName, arg1, arg2, ...)); // How to implement this in my class A
```

My sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
//#include <boost/*.hpp> // You can use any boost library if needed

// How to implement this class to take a handler with variable number of arguments?
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {

    }

    void Do()
    {
        // How to call the handler with variable number of arguments?
    }
};

void FreeFunctionWithoutArgument()
{
    std::cout << "FreeFunctionWithoutArgument is called" << std::endl;
}

void FreeFunctionWithOneArgument(int x)
{
    std::cout << "FreeFunctionWithOneArgument is called, x = " << x << std::endl;
}

void FreeFunctionWithTwoArguments(int x, std::string s)
{
    std::cout << "FreeFunctionWithTwoArguments is called, x = " << x << ", s =" << s << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    A a;

    a.Do(); // Will do different jobs depending on which FreeFunction is passed to the class A
}
```

P.S.: you can use any boost library if needed, such as boost::bind, boost::function

Comment: `async_wait` is just taking a functor in that code; `boost::bind` is doing all the real work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class A {
  public:
    A() {}

    typedef boost::function<void()> Handler;
    void Do(Handler h) {
        h();
    }
};

... 
A a;
int arg1;
std::string arg2;
a.Do(&FreeFunctionWithNoArguments);
a.Do(boost::bind(&FreeFunctionWithOneArgument, arg1));
a.Do(boost::bind(&FreeFunctionWithTwoArguments, arg1, arg2));
```

If you have a C++1x compiler, replace `boost::` with `std::`.

Comment: You might be very interested in Lambda expression, right :-) The code works, however, I'm kind of confused how that works.  boost::bind is mysterious.  The Handler type typedef-ed here takes no argument, why will it still work. Hmm...

Comment: would you mind having a look at my another post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076524/why-my-eventtimer-implemented-by-boostasioio-service-and-boostdeadline-time